# Referencing InfoWindowLite in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, infowindow, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to add in the info window function using JavaScript. Besides that, I have added in FeatureLayers, a Legend and Scalebar. However, the moment I try to add in my InfoWindow, everything disappears when I try to run it in chrome. I am aware that the sequence that the attributes are placed in the JavaScript matters, but I have no idea where to paste the InfoWindow. I am using Notepad++.

Here's the code before I attempted to add in the InfoWindow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>

<style>
 html, body{
 height: 97%;
 width: 98%;
 margin: 1%;
 }
 #rightPane {
 width: 20%;
 }
 #legendPane {
 border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
 }

 </style>

<script>
 var map;
 require([
 "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend",
 "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser", "esri/dijit/Scalebar", 
 "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
"dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",  "dojo/domReady!"
 ], function(
 Map, FeatureLayer, Legend,
 arrayUtils, parser, Scalebar
 ) {
 parser.parse();
 map = new Map("map", {
 basemap:"topo",
 center: [-98.416, 39.781],
 zoom: 6
 });
 // scalebar
  var scalebar = new Scalebar({
      map: map,
      // "dual" displays both miles and kilmometers
      // "english" is the default, which displays miles
      // use "metric" for kilometers
      scalebarUnit: "dual", attachTo:"bottom-center"

    });

 // feature layer
     var featureLayer = new 
 FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3", {
 mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
 outFields:["STATE_NAME", "SUB_REGION", "STATE_ABBR"]
 });
 map.addLayer(featureLayer);

 map.infoWindow.resize(200,75);


 //add the legend
 map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
 var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
 return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
 });
 if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
 var legendDijit = new Legend({
 map: map,
 layerInfos: layerInfo
 }, "legendDiv");
 legendDijit.startup();
 }
 });
 map.addLayers([featureLayer]);
 });

 var legendFeature = new
FeatureLayer("http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/TOC/MapServer/6", {
 mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
 outFields:["*"]
 });


 </script>



</head>

<body class="claro">
<div id="content" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
 <div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
     <div id="legendDiv"></div>
     </div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
     This pane could contain tools or additional content
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="overflow:hidden;">

 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the code after I tried to add in the references for the InfoWindow (whereby everything disappears)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- add in meta elements -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Mock Practical</title>
    <!-- reference styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <!-- reference arcGIS javascript -->
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
    <style>
     html, body{
     height: 97%;
     width: 98%;
     margin: 1%;
     }
     #rightPane {
     width: 20%;
     }
     #legendPane {
     border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
     }

     </style>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script>
     var map;
     require([
     "esri/map", "esri/dijit/infoWindowLite", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/Legend",
     "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/parser", "esri/dijit/Scalebar", 
     "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
    "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer","dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"
     ], function(
     Map, InfoWindowLite, InfoTemplate, FeatureLayer, Legend,
     arrayUtils, parser, Scalebar, domConstruct
     ) {
     parser.parse();
     map = new Map("map", {
     basemap:"topo",
     center: [-98.416, 39.781],
     zoom: 6
     });
     // scalebar
      var scalebar = new Scalebar({
          map: map,
          // "dual" displays both miles and kilmometers
          // "english" is the default, which displays miles
          // use "metric" for kilometers
          scalebarUnit: "dual", attachTo:"bottom-center"

        });

     // feature layer
         var featureLayer = new 
     FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3", {
     mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
     outFields:["STATE_NAME", "SUB_REGION", "STATE_ABBR"]
     });
     map.addLayer(featureLayer);

     map.infoWindow.resize(200,75);


     //add the legend
     map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
     var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
     return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
     });
     if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
     var legendDijit = new Legend({
     map: map,
     layerInfos: layerInfo
     }, "legendDiv");
     legendDijit.startup();
     }
     });
     map.addLayers([featureLayer]);
     });

     var legendFeature = new
    FeatureLayer("http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/TOC/MapServer/6", {
     mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
     outFields:["*"]
     });


     </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
<div id="content" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
 <div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legend', selected:true">
     <div id="legendDiv"></div>
     </div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
     This pane could contain tools or additional content
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="overflow:hidden;">

 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require path of this widget  is "esri/dijit/InfoWindowLite" instead of "..infoWindowLite"